# How to determine if a class is a subclass of other class?

Tags: java

I'd like to check if a Class object represents a subclass of other class 
for example

```
Class class1 = Class.forName("Class1");
Class class2 = Class.forName("Class2");

 if(class1.isSubClassOf(class2)) // fake methos isSubClassOf
{
  // do sth
}
```

How can I implement this `isSubClassOf` method ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Class.isAssignableFrom() provides more-or-less what you're after, although it handle interfaces also, so may need to do a bit more extra work to be sure that it's a subclass, direct or otherwise.

Comment: I got all mixed up about which class was which, reading the javadoc for that method. To put this here for the benefit of everyone else: If you have `class SubClass extends SuperClass`: `SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(SubClass.class)` is true, while `SubClass.class.isAssignableFrom(SuperClass.class)` is false. So it's kind of the reverse of the OP's fictitious `isSubClassOf` method.